# Using diff-buffer-with-file to merge differences between the disk and the buffer

Tags: async, diff

I sync my org files via Dropbox. Occasionally, Dropbox will bring in changes into a file whose buffer I've already modified. I can diff the buffer and the file on disk with `diff-buffer-with-file`; but then what?

Theoretically it's a `diff` minor mode file, so I should be able to use diff functions such as `(diff-apply-hunk)`, but in practice a get an elisp stack trace.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better approach?

Comment: Sounds like a bug.  So I'd recommend `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: As a workaround (or not, as the case may be), see whether you have better success with the `ediff` variant, which is `ediff-current-file`.